# Color gradient effect in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

[image: example]

I'd like to get the effect of this picture. I know R and python can do this.

But can matlab do this?

Comment: A picture would be a start...

Comment: For linear shading, look at https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6985-drawshadedrectangle

Comment: Check out the data density map function.

Comment: Thank you. My english is poor.